# Probability of picking a number from a set with a uncountably infinite number of positive numbers and a countably infinite number of negative numbers?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, random, infinite-groups

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I couldn't see anything else quite the same as this, although I found some similar questions. Please remove this if it is a duplicate. (I hardly understand sets so please take the spirit of the question into account and give me ways to phrase it better. Thank you!)

Note: I am assuming a uniform distribution. (If you can even do that for an uncountably infinite set.)

Note 2: I have realized that this problem doesn't work, as I cannot assign a  uniform distribution to an uncountable infinite set. If anyone knows a way to somehow bypass this, please comment. Thank you!

Note 3: Someone told me the exact opposite thing that the earlier person said, so I now have no idea what is true or not.

Note 4: I have come to the conclusion that you $can$, in fact, assign a uniform distribution to an uncountably infinite set, and the method of picking the random number doesn't matter since this is a theoretical exercise. Thank you.

My question is essentially this: If you had the set $S$, $[0,1] \cup \Bbb Z$, and you randomly picked a number from the set, is it more likely for the selected number to be in between $0$ and $1$ or an integer $\Bbb Z$? I feel like it's logical that the number should be more likely to be in between $1$ and $0$, as there are infinitely many more numbers in between $1$ and $0$ than all integers $\Bbb Z$, but I also know that technically the probability of selecting any number at all is $0$. Would it just be an equal probability of $0$, or would it be a $100%$ chance of something in $[0,1]$ being selected? Or would it be something else? Thank you!

Thank you!

Edit 1: Clarified the set more, and changed it from strictly negative $\Bbb I$ into a general $\Bbb I$.

Edit 2: Added Note 2.

Edit 3: Added Note 3.

Edit 4: Question has been properly cleaned up, Note 4 has been added.

Comment: You need to be more precise on the distribution and also selection method.

Comment: Hmm, I knew I needed to make something more precise. I think I can clarify the distribution some more by simplifying it to just all integers, but I don't know how to be more precise on the selection method. Is there a way to randomly select from an uncountably infinite set?

Comment: Picking from an infinite set using a uniform distribution cannot be done, since all have the same probability and must sum to 1.  Random number generators are based on a very large finite set (typically ~ $10^{10}$) uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

Comment: Interesting. it appears that I can't simply assign equal probability to each element, which is very annoying. I suppose this is probably an impossible question if I wanted it to be truly random? Thank you!

Comment: You can have a uniform distribution on an uncountably infinite set. But you can't have a uniform distribution on a countably infinite set.

Comment: Wait, so this does work? Since I imagine a set with an uncountably large amount of numbers inside would be an uncountably large set.

Comment: Fundamental problem:  how do you pick one?  Uniform distribution is perfectly possible on an infinite set, such as the unit interval.  However there is no method for picking one number.

Comment: I am informed [by some random strangers on the internet] that it doesn't particularly matter that it's impossible/hard to randomly pick a number, but what matters is "What would happen if we did?", so that's a moot point.

Answer (score 2):

If your space of probability is $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ with Borel's $\sigma$-algebra, I'd say that you do have a grater chance of picking a positive number: $-\mathbb{Z}$ is a nullset while $[0,1]$ is not. How ever, I am no Probability Theory expert and you should probably listen to someone who knows better than I do, but I reckon that having a nullset and a set of positive measure is key to this.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly your problem, but it is well known and understood that one *can* define things such that we have an uncountably infinite probability space equipped with a uniform probability measure.  More specifically, an example of this is the real interval $[0,1]$ equipped with the [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure).

The Lebesgue measure here is the intuitive "how long is the interval" measure you are used to but formalized in such a way as to cover all of the frustrating cases that might arise.

> (*Do note however that in attempting to formalize things, one does open the door for some rather bizarre outcomes such as [non-measurable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set) so care must be taken*)

Let $A = \{\frac{1}{2^n}~:~n\in\Bbb N\}$.  We do indeed in this situation have $\Pr([0,1]\setminus A) = 1$ and $\Pr(A)=0$ as any countable set is a nullset according to the Lebesgue measure.

Indeed, in any scenario in which you attempt to define a "uniform" distribution (*whatever that means in your context*) using whatever specific probability measure it is over an uncountable sample space, the probability of landing in a countable subset of that will be zero.  This follows from the probability space axioms.

Specifically, [the third axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom) states that the probability measure must satisfy $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(A_n) = \Pr(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$ for any countable sequence of disjoint events $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

In particular with a "uniform" distribution you would surely be insisting that $\Pr(\{x\})=\Pr(\{y\})$ for any $x,y$ which along with the third axiom of sigma-additivity imply that probability of any individual element must be zero and further that probability of any countable subset of elements must be zero.